# Import negative numbers with SSIS 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis, import

I'm importing a flat txt file into SQL Server 2005 using SSIS. The problem is that negative numbers between -1 and 0 in the txt file are in a format without leading zero, e.g.:

-.15

If I insert such number into my database using plain INSERT syntax it works without complaining. However, SSIS reports an error if it encounter such number. If I change the number in txt file to:

-0.15

SSIS works correctly. Is this a known problem and is there any way to solve it without changing the values in the source txt file?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but: 1. Are language / decimal separator settings different for you import (other than just firing the SQL from the manamgent studio), and 2: are you setting the field type correctly? (http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/07/flat-file-sources-and-the-decimal-data-type/). 3: if all else fails, perhaps you can import as a different type and run your own procedure on the data post-import.

Comment: Thanks, Tobias. Decimal separator is OK and data type is also OK. As for suggestion in point 3. you're right but I'll do this if everything else fails.

Comment: Hm, in fact, the problem doesn't arise just with negative decimals between -1 and 0, but with positive decimals between 0 and 1 as well, e.g.:

.1

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to copy the error message:
"The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data"

In the next line of the error description, there is a row number where such number occurs for the first time. Therefore, it must really be some sort of a problem with decimals between -1 and 1, and without a zero number before the decimal separator.

Comment: Tobias, you were right - I had to change my regional settings to have point (.) for decimal separator (it was comma before) and it works now.

However, is there any way to create SSIS in a such way that it works on any computer with any given regional settings decimal separator if one knows decimal data will always use point as a decimal separator.

You may post your answer to get an answered mark from me if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type on the flat file source side and what is the data type on the destination side?  Have you tried using an explicit data conversion step?  It sounds like an implicit conversion is occurring and it isn't working correctly, so explicitly setting the types may resolve the problem.

Comment: It is float and I am using DT_R8 as a data type. As I already answered Tobias, the problem was caused by a different decimal separator in my regional settings. Thanks anyway for explicit data conversion hint - reading some articles about this option forced me to learn much more about SSIS.